# ActiveRecord conditional order clause

Tags: activerecord, conditional-statements

I need to sort a list of tasks:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| title                            | priority    | due_at              |
| ---------------------------------|-------------|---------------------|
|  Mow the lawn                    |           1 | 2011-09-11 22:00:00 |
|  Call mom                        |           3 | 2010-01-26 09:29:03 |
|  Bake a cake                     |           2 | 2013-09-13 08:45:37 |
|  Feed the cat                    |           2 | 2015-09-12 16:03:51 |
|  Remember you don't like the cat |           2 | 2014-03-19 23:00:00 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

The order clause should sort overdue tasks by priority, all others by  due_at, e.g. the resulting order should be

- Mow the lawn
- Bake a cake
- Call mom
- Remember you don't like the cat
- Feed the cat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with the following (plain SQL, not yet translated to AR):

```
SELECT *
FROM tasks 
ORDER BY 
    due_at <= Now() DESC,
    CASE due_at <= Now()  WHEN true THEN priority END ASC,
    CASE due_at <= Now()  WHEN true THEN due_at END ASC,
    CASE due_at <= Now()  WHEN false THEN due_at END DESC,
    CASE due_at <= Now()  WHEN false THEN priority END ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need an array of the tasks stored in `@tasks` you can do this:

```
@tasks = Task.where(due_at: 10.years.ago..Time.now).order(:priority)
@tasks += Task.where.not(due_at: 10.years.ago..Time.now).order(:due_at)
```

If you need an `Task::ActiveRecord_Relation` you'll have to do this:

```
Task.where(id: Task.where(due_at: 10.years.ago..Time.now).
               order(:priority).pluck(:id) + 
               Task.where.not(due_at: 10.years.ago..Time.now).
               order(:due_at).pluck(:id))
```